# subset of dataframe in R using a predefined list of names

Tags: r, dataframe, subset, matching

I have a list of gene names called "COMBO_mk_plt_genes_labels" and a dataframe of marker genes called "Marker_genes_41POS_12_libraries_test_1"  containing genes and fold changes.

I want to extract the names of COMBO_mk_plt_genes_labels.

I know that the `which()` function in R would get the positions of the genes. See my example below. How do I extract the names and not only the position?

```r
print(head(Marker_genes_41POS_12_libraries_test_1))
```

> p_val avg_logFC pct.1 pct.2     p_val_adj
>
> HBD      6.610971e-108 3.3357135 0.930 0.080 2.419682e-103
>
> GP1BB     1.332211e-91 2.5397301 0.825 0.047  4.876024e-87
>
> CMTM5     1.938091e-63 2.0580724 0.605 0.005  7.093606e-59
>
> SH3BGRL3  1.067771e-60 1.3750032 0.975 0.592  3.908149e-56
>
> PF4       1.899932e-60 3.0111590 0.371 0.000  6.953941e-56
>
> FTH1      4.242081e-58 0.8947325 0.996 0.905  1.552644e-53

```r
COMBO_mk_plt_genes=read.csv(file = "combined_Mk_Plt_genes_list.csv", row.names = ,1)

COMBO_mk_plt_genes_labels=COMBO_mk_plt_genes[,1]

print(head(COMBO_mk_plt_genes_labels))
```

> [1] "CMTM5"    "GP9"      "CLEC1B"   "LTBP1"    "C12orf39" "CAMK1"

```r
PLT_genes_in_dataframe= which(rownames(Marker_genes_41POS_12_libraries_test_1) %in% COMBO_mk_plt_genes_labels)

print(PLT_genes_in_dataframe)
```

> [1]    2    3    5    8   11   12   13   20   22   23   24   27   32  38   39   42
>
> [17]   48   60   61   66   68   75   77   92   93  108 112  145  158  175  188  196
>
> [33]  203  214  236  253  261  307  308 1004 1017

I want the names of the elements not the positions. Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the base `intersect()`:

```r
intersect(rownames(Marker_genes_41POS_12_libraries_test_1), COMBO_mk_plt_genes_labels)
```

`intersect()` outputs the items that match between the two sequences of items.
Run `?intersect()` or `?base::intersect()` for more information.

**Alternative solution: Getting element names with your `which()` approach**

You can still use `which()` to find the items or element names. Knowing that your `which()` function provides the index numbers at which `rownames(Marker_genes_41POS_12_libraries_test_1)` matches `COMBO_mk_plt_genes_labels` *in* `rownames(Marker_genes_41POS_12_libraries_test_1)`, you can use those index numbers to call the element names in `rownames(Marker_genes_41POS_12_libraries_test_1)` that matched.

```r
rownames(Marker_genes_41POS_12_libraries_test_1)[which(rownames(Marker_genes_41POS_12_libraries_test_1) %in% COMBO_mk_plt_genes_labels)]

# or in short

rownames(Marker_genes_41POS_12_libraries_test_1)[PLT_genes_in_dataframe]
```

`intersect()`, though, is a simpler approach.

**However, there is one difference you need to be aware of and that is with duplicated items.**
 If the rownames(...) (let's call it `x`) has duplicates that match with items in the second sequence of items `y`, `intersect(x, y)` will not provide you any duplicates. In contrast, the `x[which(x %in% y)]` (i.e., the `which()` approach) will provide you duplicated `x` where the match with `y` in `x` is TRUE. Switch `x` and `y` and you can get duplicated `y` names, too, using `y[which(y %in% x)]`. You can use this for something like tallying the number of times that there was a match.